# What happened to types.ClassType in python 3?

Tags: class, types, python-3.x

I have a script where I do some magic stuff to dynamically load a module, and instantiate the first class found in the module. But I can't use `types.ClassType` anymore in Python 3. What is the correct way to do this now?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems that classes are of type "type". Here is an example of how to distinguish between classes and other objects at runtime.

```
>>> class C: pass
... 
>>> type(C)
<class 'type'>
>>> isinstance(C, type)
True
>>> isinstance('string', type)
False
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using `type(C) is type`, which worked for simple classes, but not when C uses a metaclass. `isinstance(C, type)`, as you wrote, still returns `True` in that case, however.

Answer (score 6):

It was used for [classic classes](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html). In Python 3 they're gone.
I suppose you could use something like:

```
issubclass(ClassName, object)
```

Comment: This will throw if the `ClassName` variable happens to be not a class type. For example `issubclass('hello', object)` will throw.