# Instance is an "object", but class is not a subclass of "object": how is this possible?

Tags: python, object, instance, subclass

How is it possible to have an instance of a class which is an `object`, without the class being a subclass of `object`?  here is an example:

```
>>> class OldStyle(): pass
>>> issubclass(OldStyle, object)
False
>>> old_style = OldStyle()
>>> isinstance(old_style, object)
True
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Python 2, *type* and *class* are not the same thing, specifically, for old-style classes, `type(obj)` [is not the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) as `obj.__class__`. So it is possible because instances of old-style classes are actually of a different type (`instance`) than their class:

```
>>> class A(): pass
>>> class B(A): pass
>>> b = B()

>>> assert b.__class__ is B
>>> issubclass(b.__class__, A) # same as issubclass(B, A)
True
>>> issubclass(type(b), A)
False

>>> type(b)
<type 'instance'>
>>> b.__class__
<class __main__.B at 0x10043aa10>
```

This is resolved in new-style classes:

```
>>> class NA(object): pass
>>> class NB(NA): pass
>>> nb = NB()
>>> issubclass(type(nb), NA)
True
>>> type(nb)
<class '__main__.NB'>
>>> nb.__class__
<class '__main__.NB'>
```

Old-style class is not a type, new-style class is:

```
>>> isinstance(A, type)
False
>>> isinstance(NA, type)
True
```

Old style classes are declared deprecated. In Python 3, there are only new-style classes; `class A()` is equivalent to `class A(object)` and your code will yield `True` in both checks.

Take a look at this question for some more discussion: [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

Comment: +1: This is a very clear description, and a very good point. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone wondering, `isinstance` is [special-cased](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e6a0b5982973e64b9fa28e5e3e54eb8c47882780/Objects/abstract.c#L2898) for old-style instances and classes (i.e. `PyClass_Check(cls) && PyInstance_Check(inst)` in C). Since there's no type-based relationship, it gets the `__class__` of the instance for an `issubclass` check, which is also [special-cased](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e6a0b5982973e64b9fa28e5e3e54eb8c47882780/Objects/classobject.c#L486) for old-style classes.

Answer (score 6):

Everything is an object:

```
isinstance(123, object) # True
isinstance("green cheese", object) # True
isinstance(someOldClassObject, object) # True
isinstance(someNewClassObject, object) # True
isinstance(object, object) # True
isinstance(None, object) # True
```

Note that this question has essentially nothing to do with old- vs. new-style classes. `isinstance(old_style, object)` being `True` is simply a corollary of the fact that every value in python is an instance of `object`.

Comment: Do you have a reference on this?

Comment: @EOL: [this one](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html) is quite helpful

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the reference, but I can't find anywhere any indication of the idea that everything in Python is of *type* `object` (the fact that "everything is an object" in Python does not mean the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

When you do the expression

```
   old_style = OldStyle()
```

It means you are instantiating the object, which old_style is an instance of the class OldStyle.

Also, both evaluates to True in Python 3.2.