# Why does isinstance(nonnewstyle, object) return true in Python 2.X?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, types, new-style-class

I am reading a textbook on Python and it covers new-style class differences. Observe the following code in Python 2.X in the interpreter, which uses classic classes:

```
class C: pass
X = C()
isinstance(X, object) #returns true
isinstance(C, object) #returns true
```

(To use new-style classes, one must explicitly derive from the object class in 2.X)

So how can an object that does not derive (as is the case in classic classes) from the object class be an instance of object? What is going on behind the scenes in the case of 3.X and 2.X?

As for whether this is a duplicate question: I already knew that everything was technically an object, I was wondering how the discrepancy is handled explicitly in the design of python itself, rather than taking the results of isinstance for granted.

Comment: **Everything** is an object. `isinstance(object, object)` is true too.

Comment: A more useful check would be `isinstance(C, type)`, or `issubclass(C, object)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instance is an "object", but class is not a subclass of "object": how is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699591/instance-is-an-object-but-class-is-not-a-subclass-of-object-how-is-this-po)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Everything** in Python is an instance of `object`, including `object` itself:

```
>>> isinstance(object, object)
True
```

That's because the [`type.__instancecheck__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__instancecheck__) returns `True` when passed in `object` for `self`, no matter what the other argument (remember that special methods are looked up on `type(something)`, not on `something` itself, and have `self` passed in manually).

If you want to test for old-style classes, a far more useful test is if the class is an instance of `type`, or a **subclass** of `object`:

```
>>> isinstance(C, type)
False
>>> issubclass(C, object)
False
```

Either of these tests is true for new-style classes:

```
>>> class Newstyle(object): pass
...
>>> isinstance(Newstyle, type)
True
>>> issubclass(Newstyle, object)
True
```

For instances, test wether they are an instance of [`types.InstanceType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.InstanceType):

```
>>> isinstance(X, InstanceType)
True
```

Comment: I think I half understand this, that everything is an object etc. But how can something be an instance of object, and yet not subclass object?

Comment: @user3751940: forget about instance checks on object; the test is a *virtual* one, because of the `__instancecheck__` hook.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confusing `isinstance` with `issubclass`. Old style classes don't *derive* from `object` meaning that the result of `issubclass(C, object)` will be `False`. New style classes, on the other hand, always contain `object` (directly or indirectly) as a base class.

Everything is an instance of `object`. So doing `isinstance(C, object)` or `isinstance(x, object)` will always be `True`.

Answer (score 0):

X is an old-style instance of the old-style class C, which is not a subclass of `object`.

However, all objects, even old-style instances, are instances of some type (a.k.a. new-style class). The type of all old-style instances is `types.InstanceType`; together with `types.ClassType`, the type of old-style classes, these two types are responsible for the implementation of the old-style class system.

`types.InstanceType` is a subclass of `object`, as are all new-style classes. `isinstance(X, object)` returns true not because X's old-style class inherits from `object`, but because its new-style class does.