# How to check if object is instance of new-style user-defined class?

Tags: python, python-2.x, new-style-class

Code:

```
import types


class C(object):
    pass


c = C()
print(isinstance(c, types.InstanceType))
```

Output:

```
False
```

What correct way to check if object is instance of user-defined class for new-style classes?

### UPD:

I want put additional emphasize on if checking if type of object is *user-defined*. According to docs:

> **types.InstanceType** 
>          The type of instances of *user-defined* classes.

### UPD2:

Alright - not "correct" ways are OK too.

### UPD3:

Also noticed that there is no type for `set` in module `types`

Comment: This is an odd need, what is it for?

Comment: Im trying to write a simple function to measure how much memory takes object provided as argument

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand.  Why do you need to know if it's a user-defined class? What will you do in the yes case that's different than the no case?

Comment: @NedBatchelder Probably it was `__slots__` issue or something like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine the `x.__class__` check with the presence (or not) of either `'__dict__' in dir(x)` or `hasattr(x, '__slots__')`, as a hacky way to distinguish between both new/old-style class and user/builtin object.

Actually, this exact same suggestions appears in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654806/1832154

```
def is_instance_userdefined_and_newclass(inst):
    cls = inst.__class__
    if hasattr(cls, '__class__'):
        return ('__dict__' in dir(cls) or hasattr(cls, '__slots__'))
    return False
```

---

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> class B(object): pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> is_instance_userdefined_and_newclass(1)
False
>>> is_instance_userdefined_and_newclass(a)
False
>>> is_instance_userdefined_and_newclass(b)
True
```

Comment: Except that that will fail with objects defined in a c library. I guess the term hackish is appropriate.

Comment: @Antimony do you typically create (i.e. code) a class in a C library and load it while running a python code ? By user-defined I simply took that the user created it purely using Python, without relying on the CPython API with C code. And I'm aware this method can fail, but there is nothing else that works for the given question (your answer doesn't).

Comment: @mmgp Seems like this is the answer, thank you! I will wait 4 days more and accept/award your answer if no less hackish solutions will be posted.

Comment: **Brilliant.** I needed this today for precisely the same reason Gill needed this three years ago: [memory profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612865/how-to-check-if-object-is-instance-of-new-style-user-defined-class#comment20486559_14612865). When recursively profiling the space consumed by _user-defined_ objects and the complete tree of _user-defined_ referents those objects transitively refer to, recursion naturally bottoms out at _built-in_ objects. This simple (albeit hackish) test just saved my Canadian bacon.

Comment: Relatedly, the last three lines of `is_instance_userdefined_and_newclass()` reduce to a single statement: `return hasattr(cls, '__class__') and ('__dict__' in dir(cls) or hasattr(cls, '__slots__'))`. Negligible efficiency gains for the win.

Comment: See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41012823/2809027), generalizing the above answer to reliably detect both pure-Python classes _and_ class instances in a Python 3.x-specific manner – complete with wild and/or crazy CPython optimization.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about the "correct" way, but one easy way to test it is that instances of old style classes have the type 'instance' instead of their actual class.

So `type(x) is x.__class__` or `type(x) is not types.InstanceType` should both work.

```
>>> class Old:
...     pass
...
>>> class New(object):
...     pass
...
>>> x = Old()
>>> y = New()
>>> type(x) is x.__class__
False
>>> type(y) is y.__class__
True
>>> type(x) is types.InstanceType
True
>>> type(y) is types.InstanceType
False
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I'll add the link in your answer, if you don't mind

Comment: Feel free to add the link.

Comment: Actually `type(x) is x.__class__` returns `True` even if `x = 1`. So this way is not similar to `isinstance(x, types.InstanceType)`

Comment: I can't edit your question yet, but [here's the relevant question with more information about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/)

Comment: @Gill that's because `int` is a new style class. Based on your actual edited question, it looks like you're out of luck.

Comment: @Antimony question initially was about user-defined classes, in edits I just highlighted this.

Comment: @Gill well it depends on what you mean by a 'user defined' type, but I don't think there's any easy or reliable way to do want you want. The whole point is that the builtin types aren't any different than what you can create.

Comment: @Antimony I think of user-defined classes as about complex classes that built on basic classes such as int/str/float etc.

Comment: @Gill but there's no difference between them. At best you can hack something together using a manual list of builtin types or using `inspect` to try to find out where the class was defined, but it's ugly and unreliable.

Comment: @Antimony There is a difference - how can you build your own class, without using basic types? You cant operate with ones and zeroes in memory, and you must rely to basic types - that's my point.

Comment: @Gill the builtin types don't "operate on ones or zeroes" either. In the particular case of CPython, they're wrappers around C code, but you can just as easily define your own types based on C code.

Comment: @Antimony How can you say that Python objects are the same as types, if at the same time you say that, you need to dive into lower-level code of particular implementation of language to define types. Alright - they "unified" in Python, but that's doesnt mean that they are same, that gives to programmer ability to inherit basic types in Python - that is one of the goals of unification. Purpose of "types" is human-friendly interpretation binary data. Purpose of objects is to organize code using OO approach.

Answer (score 1):

This tells us True if it is.

```
if issubclass(checkthis, (object)) and 'a' not in vars(__builtins__):print"YES!"
```

The second argument is a tuple of the classes to be checked.
This is easy to understand and i'm sure it works.
[edit (object) to(object,) thanks Duncan!]

Comment: Your second argument is simply `object`. The parentheses don't magically turn it into a tuple: commas make tuples so `(object,)` would be a one element tuple. However in this case passing just `object` works fine because the second argument of `issubclass()` can be either a class or a tuple of things that `issubclass()` takes as its second argument. (Yes, the definition is recursive so you can use nested tuples of classes.)

Comment: `issubclass(int, (object,))` also returns `True` and so doesn't do what the OP asked for.

Comment: Actually, the OP said 'not "correct" answers', which I understood to mean something that works even if it's not an official way. But I can see the confusion: downvote removed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I can go with elimination method - not checking if object is instance of user-defined class explicitly - `isinstance(object, RightTypeAliasForThisCase)`, but checking if object not one of 'basic' types.