# Boost.Python.class and pylint "super-on-old-class" and "no-member" errors

Tags: python, boost-python, pylint

I have a base class those type is `Boost.Python.class` as it is a wrapper to a C++ class in a C++ library. I inherit from it, and want to call the base class initiator method like so:

```
class Child(Parent):
   def __init__(self):
       super(Child, self).__init__()
```

In addition, the `Parent` class has a method called `start` which clearly the child should be able to call.  However, if I run pylint, I get these errors:

```
E: 21, 4: Use of super on an old style class (super-on-old-class)
E: 39, 8: Instance of 'Client' has no 'start' member (no-member)
```

It is something I am doing wrong, and if so what?

Is it a bug in pylint?

Note that using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14654622/232794), the function given seems to think that Client is a user defined and a new class. Clearly, if I run the full code, `super` and `start` are correctly called.

Comment: We need more code -- the actual code you are running. Presumably you are defining `Child` via `class Child`... somewhere. Also, there's no `.start()` call in your example to correspond to the second line of your error output.

Comment: @PaulBissex: Too much code to copy and paste here. The Parent class is a C++ class wrapped in boost::python.

Comment: Use a pastebin if needed. Do some editing/elision if needed. If you want an answer, make it easier to give an answer. Your question has been sitting here for six months and nobody has taken a stab at it.